# one of my view does not appears in my master - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to do @yield to one of my partials into my master.blade.php, which includes form and ajax . It does not work. All the rest of my partials appear without any issue, except this one . Any ideas?
I am trying to do @yield to one of my partials into my master.blade.php, which includes form and ajax . It does not work. All the rest of my partials appear without any issue, except this one . Any ideas?

Here is my code :

search.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')

@section('search')

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
<div class="row"> 
<div class="container">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <input class="typeahead form-control" style="width:300px;" type="text" placeholder="Search Products">
          </form>

</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

My master.blade.php :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@if (!empty($title) )
        {{ $title }}  
        @else 
        MyHero 
        @endif</title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
    <link href="{{ asset('carousel.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>    
    <script>var BASE_URL = "{{ url('')}}/";</script>  


</head>

<header> 
    <!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
    <body>
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/')}}">MyHero</a> 

                        </div> 
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 

                                @if( !empty($menu)) 
                                @foreach($menu as $item) 
                                <li><a href="{{ url($item['url'])}}">{{ $item['link'] }}</a></li> 
                                @endforeach 
                                @endif

                                <li><a href="{{ url('shop')}}">Shop</a></li> 
                                <li> 
                                    <a href="{{ url('shop/checkout')}}">
                                        <img width="20" src="{{ asset('images/shopping-cart.png')}}">  
                                        <div id="total-cart"> 
                                            @if(! Cart::isEmpty()) 
                                            {{Cart::getTotalQuantity()}}
                                            @endif
                                        </div> 

                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>  

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
                                @if(Session::has('user_id')) 
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/edit')}}">{{ Session::get('user_name') }}</a></li>   
                                @if( Session::has('is_admin'))
                                <li><a href="{{ url('cms/dashboard')}}">CMS DASHBOARD</a></li>  
                                @endif
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/logout')}}">Logout</a></li> 
                                @else
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/signin')}}">Sign In</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/signup')}}">Sign Up</a></li>  

                                @endif
                            </ul> 

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </div>




</header>  <br><br><br><br> 

<div class="container" > @yield('search')</div>


<div class="container" >@yield('carousel')</div> <br><br>
<main>  
    <div class="container"> 

        @include ('inc.sm')
        @include ('inc.errors')


        @yield('content')  

    </div> 

</main>  
<br><br><br>
<footer>  
    <div class="container">  
        <hr>
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-12" > 
                <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 18px;" >MyHero &copy; {{ date('Y') }} </p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</footer>    



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just `@include` the search partial instead of yielding? That should work as long as your controller is returning the `search` view. Also, try and move the scripts out of search.

Comment: My controller is returning my search view. I tried to do what you said above and it creates HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to need little tweaks in sequence of script references.

You have different versions jquery library in search view and master view. In search view you added reference of version `1.9.1`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

And in master view, jquery version is `3.2.1`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1. Decide which version you want to continue with and pick a single
   version.
2. It is possible that your script in search view depends upon some other script file in master, so that should be loaded first in browser before script in search view start execution. Try remove all script code from search view, put only html(form in your case) in this view, and place related script in master view below other scripts.

Comment: The thing with putting my script from my search blade inside my master kinda worked!What I did I put my form as it is in my master and my script as it is in my master. My auto complete suggestions work , but its not showing me the results of my search

Comment: It may be problem with AJAX request. any error message you are getting?

Comment: I posted a new question about that,  if you can help I would appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904672/displaying-results-from-autocomplete-search-laravel/45904848?noredirect=1#comment78769155_45904848