# Displaying results from AutoComplete search Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

I applied Typeahead autocomplete search to my "master.blade" and now I have search field available inside my navigation bar that is included everywhere inside my site. My autocomplete suggestions work fine but its not showing me the searched results. How can I display the search results?

My routes:

```
Route::get('search',array('as'=>'search','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@search'));
Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@autocomplete'));
```

My AutoCompleteController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;
class AutoCompleteController extends MainController {

      public function search()
    {
        return view('master');
    }

       public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Product::select("title")->where("title","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")->get();
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

My master.blade:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@if (!empty($title) )
        {{ $title }}  
        @else 
        MyHero 
        @endif</title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
    <link href="{{ asset('carousel.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>    
    <script>var BASE_URL = "{{ url('')}}/";</script>  


</head>

<header> 
    <!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
    <body>
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/')}}">MyHero</a> 

                        </div> 
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 

                                @if( !empty($menu)) 
                                @foreach($menu as $item) 
                                <li><a href="{{ url($item['url'])}}">{{ $item['link'] }}</a></li> 
                                @endforeach 
                                @endif

                                <li><a href="{{ url('shop')}}">Shop</a></li> 
                                <li> 
                                    <a href="{{ url('shop/checkout')}}">
                                        <img width="20" src="{{ asset('images/shopping-cart.png')}}">  
                                        <div id="total-cart"> 
                                            @if(! Cart::isEmpty()) 
                                            {{Cart::getTotalQuantity()}}
                                            @endif
                                        </div> 

                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>  

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
                                @if(Session::has('user_id')) 
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/edit')}}">{{ Session::get('user_name') }}</a></li>   
                                @if( Session::has('is_admin'))
                                <li><a href="{{ url('cms/dashboard')}}">CMS DASHBOARD</a></li>  
                                @endif
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/logout')}}">Logout</a></li> 
                                @else
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/signin')}}">Sign In</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/signup')}}">Sign Up</a></li>  

                                @endif
                            </ul> 
                            <div class="row"> 
                            <div class="container">
                            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                            <input class="typeahead form-control" style="width:300px;" type="text" placeholder="Search Products">
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </div>




</header>  <br><br><br><br> 




<div class="container" >@yield('carousel')</div> <br><br>
<main>  
    <div class="container"> 

        @include ('inc.sm')
        @include ('inc.errors')


        @yield('content')  

    </div> 

</main>  
<br><br><br>
<footer>  
    <div class="container">  
        <hr>
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-12" > 
                <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 18px;" >MyHero &copy; {{ date('Y') }} </p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</footer>    



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You said *autocomplete suggestions work fine* so it seems that when you start typing the searching key, it will suggest you related records. And *noy showing the searched results*, it needs more explanation, is your `search` function is being called successfully, or getting any error message? where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @M_Idrees in my console I got 500 (Internal Server Error) while typing ,when I click search it says "Navigated to http://localhost/myhero/public/?search=Superman"(which is my base url plus the word I typed) in my console , but stays on the same page

Comment: Its little confusing, now you are saying you got 500 error while typing, then what you mean when you said *autocomplete suggestions work fine* ?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a model to JSON, you should use the `toJson()` method. Like `toArray`, the `toJson` method is recursive, so all attributes and relations will be converted to JSON:

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {

if( !empty(request('query'))){
        $data = Product::select("title")
        ->where("title","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
->get();
     $dataJson =$data->toJson();
        return view('master', compact('dataJson'));
}else

   return view ('master');

    }
```

If you really want to use json encoded data in a view, use `json_decode()` in foreach:

```
@if($dataJson)
    @foreach(json_decode($dataJson, true) as $value)
       {{ $value['record1']['record 2'] }}   
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand this part : @foreach(json_decode($mydata, true) as $value)
   {{ $value['record1']['record 2'] }}   
@endforeach  . Do I put it my master view and if yes where execatly?

Comment: it should be $dataJson instead my mistake that foreach loops the json data and print them out in the blade. The foreach should be in the view exactly where you want to display the results.

Comment: please check official documentation for json serialization [Laravel] and mark the question as an answer please :) thanka(https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json)

Comment: I got a mistake in my master now "Undefined variable: dataJson (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myhero\resources\views\master.blade.php)"

Comment: I did pass it as you suggested in your answer ,I still got the mistake

Comment: try on ur controller dd($dataJson); and tell what u get

Comment: hmmm thats true because there is no data to search for in input! Before you run the query check if you have data on input;  check my edited answer

Comment: I applied your changes , still got the same mistake

Comment: ok my explanation works with me all the time, check your javascript and other part of code

Comment: btw ...what is this $value['record1']['record 2']...maybe it should be something else?

Comment: check the edited answer again, we should check for variable even in the blade

Comment: Still got the same mistake.In my master blade  I got warnings that its misspelled word almost under each of this" @if($dataJson)
    @foreach(json_decode($dataJson, true) as $value)
       {{ $value['record1']['record 2'] }}   
    @endforeach
@endif"